# Errno::EHOSTUNREACH No route to host - connect(2)

Tags: ruby

```
Errno::EHOSTUNREACH in UsersController#create

No route to host - connect(2)
```

when sending mail with a Rails application am getting this error.

Comment: You give us too much information Raju. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The error `Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host - connect(2)` indicates  a routing problem and has probably something to do with a wrong IP address. You might have specified a wrong IP in `/etc/hosts` (the [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) which maps hostnames to IP addresses) or elsewhere, for instance in config/deploy.rb, etc.. If you use a local network with a DHCP server, the IP adresses can change frequently.

Answer (score 6):

Building on joeshmo's answer:

```
begin
  # problematic code
rescue Errno::EHOSTUNREACH
  # log the error
  # let the User know
rescue
  # handle other exceptions
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not apply to you, but I had a similar problem.  We've been having issues with our internal email server, the web host can't deliver emails to our own addresses on occasion.  To work around that problem which is beyond my control, and keep the 500 errors from coming through, I just caught the exception.

In the controller that sends off the emails, I wrapped the mailer call:

```
  Notifier.deliver_issue_updated(@issue, @changes, current_user)
```

Like this

```
  begin
    Notifier.deliver_issue_updated(@issue, @changes, current_user)
  rescue
    flash[:notice] += " Unable to deliver email notices."
  end
```

Now the user is notified that the email didn't go out, but not disturbed by a 500 error.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you working on chef-client deployment then it would be problem with wrong **HOST / SERVER IP** in client.rb

```
cd /etc/chef/
```

edit client.rb

```
chef_server_url "http://CORRECT_SERVER_IP:4000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got the same error. So I was using one chef server which is on `Onpremise` server 'Z' and tried to bootstrap a node 'X'. So I wrote a cookbook which writes hostnames and ipaddresses of all clients which included ip and hostname of server 'Y' to `/etc/hosts`.

So that's what the fault I made.

I was bootstrapping the nodes on cloud with chef server which is on Onpremise. 
I did changed network interface of 'Y' and forgot that client ip which is their with 'Z' is different from the present. Later I tried to bootstrap 'X' with 'Y' but since X `/etc/hosts` contains old ip of Y it was not able to find the route to host as it was trying for old ip.

Then I tried to change the old IP in `/etc/hosts` and ran `chef-client` again then everything went fine. Hope this will help you.

Remember you may face this error even when `cname` is pointing to different IP rather which it should be pointing to.

So whenever you get this error try to ssh to the chef server ip from the node you want to run chef-client and see whether you are able to connect. If it's not getting connected then it means the same thing what I explained above

Answer (score 0):

**check firewall is off or not:**
You can run following command

```
systemctl stop firewalld

systemctl disable firewalld
```